# making graphics for a Jpanel but in a different class

Tags: java, swing, class, graphics, jpanel

My program is used to animate algorithms for different data structures and I need to create all the objects that will move around.

I looked into using the Graphics class but it looks like you have to make a method to draw lines and boxes in the class that has the panels. Is there a way of drawing from an instance of the class that has the panels?

Right now I have lists working by using labels as below.

`anim` is the panel that the animated objects will be placed into. I'm trying to make a class called `PathObject` for graphs which needs the `drawline()` method in graphics but I can't find a way of adding Graphics to `anim`.
Any help would be great.

```
package Objects;

import javax.swing.*;

import Algorithms.Animated;


/** Animated object to be displayed as part of a list */
public class ListObject<T extends Number> extends AnimObject<T>
{
  // Constructor
  public ListObject(Animated anim, T val)
  {
    super(anim, val);

    Setscale(20, val.intValue());
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is here. What is `AnimObject`?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

(One friendly petition: package names in small letters, method names with beginning small letter.)

If I understand you correctly, the following would do:

You could have an interface for objects that draw something:

```
public interface Drawable {
    void paint(Graphics2D g);
}
```

Your ListObject could then `implements Drawable`.

Animated (the JPanel) could have:

```
public void addDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    drawables.add(drawable);
}
```

And in its paintComponent you could paint them.

In a way you are building your own light-weight components.